# How to make \uppercase work with Polish language?

Tags: accents, font-encodings, polish

I am trying to make `\uppercase` work with document written in Polish. However it doesn't work properly for all letters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{polski}
\begin{document}

Test:
\\
dość gróźb fuzją, klnę, pych i małżeństw
\\
\uppercase{dość gróźb fuzją, klnę, pych i małżeństw}

\end{document}
```

Result:

```
Test:
dość gróźb fuzją, klnę, pych i małżeństw
DOść GRÓŚB FUZJą, KLNę, PYCH I MAłŜEńSTW
```

As you can see, some letters are ignored (eg. `ś`), some are uppercased properly (eg. `Ó`) and some are just plain wrong (eg. `ź -> Ś`). I've been trying different combinations of `babel`/`polski`, updating all my packages with `tlmgr`, so far nothing helps.

I'm using pdflatex from TeX Live:

```
$ pdflatex -v
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
Copyright 2017 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.29; using libpng 1.6.29
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 3.04
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you know about `\MakeUppercase`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. `\uppercase` is a plain-TeX macro. For LaTeX documents, be sure to use `\MakeUppercase`.

Comment: For more information about `\uppercase` and `\MakeUppercase`, see the posting [Case-changing oddities](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-casechange.html) in the UK TeX FAQ repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make two changes:

- In LaTeX documents, use `\MakeUppercase`, not `\uppercase`.
- To typeset the ogonek accent, it's necessary to enable `T1` font encoding. Hence, run `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

If, for some reason, you cannot switch to using `\MakeUppercase`, I suggest you load the `textcase` package with the option `overload`. Doing so modifies the behavior of `\uppercase`, to make it behave like `\MakeUppercase`.

Separately, is it necessary (or even advisable) to load the `polski` package if the `babel` package is loaded with the option `polish`? I guess it depends on whether you really need the `OT4` font encoding.

And, to access really well-drawn accents, consider loading the `lmodern` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[polish]{babel}
%%\usepackage{polski}

\begin{document}
\obeylines % just for this example
Test:
dość gróźb fuzją, klnę, pych i małżeństw
\MakeUppercase{dość gróźb fuzją, klnę, pych i małżeństw}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For Polish only documents one can perhaps use `polski` that adds some features to the standard `babel` support (but doesn't allow multilingual documents). One can do `\usepackage[T1]{polski}` for choosing `T1` over `OT4` (that's to be considered obsolete).

Comment: @egreg - Thanks for this additional explanation!

Comment: Thanks @Mico. `polski` sets some extra rules like spacing and interpunction. For fonts I am using `newtxtext` anyway since my university requires Times font for all theses.